# Cross Language/Cross Platform Date and Time Transfer

Tags: date, time, cross-platform

What is the best way to transfer Dates and Times across. I am using GWT on the client/browser side and .NET C Sharp on the server and I am using JSON as data-interchange format. I am currently storing all the dates and times on the server as .NET DateTime. Now I have noticed, that if I use the GWT DatePicker or DateBox to pick a date and send it to the server as miliseconds (by doing date.getTime()) where the server takes this param as DateTime, I can see an hour offset due to the BST. I have situations where I have to have the date and time in separate boxes on the UI and the time setting along with the correct date is crucial because of scheduling.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to interchange Date and Time values would be to serialize them into culture-independent, UTC based strings like: 2010-09-18T18:37:11. The problem is, Date and Time related operations tend to be implemented incorrectly...

As for your problem, I assume that it pops up during deserialization of JSON time, i.e. .Net treats this time as local (DateTimeKind.Local or DateTimeKind.Unspecified), thus converting it. Not sure how to deal with it, the brute force would be probably sending serialized string like above and deserializing manually like this:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dateString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```

Comment: Strings are great ways to send data. Annoying sometimes, but they work in almost anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using standard such as [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) to transfer date time info in a string form. At my company, date time information encoded in JSON object is almost always in this format, e.g. "2015-10-12T18:41:11+01:00". This string can be parsed and understood correctly in all clients with different programming languages (Obj-C, Java, C/C++).